# Is it possible to "x:Bind" a property in code?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Just wondering, if there is a way to bind a property of a control to the view model in code with the new `x:Bind` in UWP? The old way it was possible with the `SetBinding` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all - WPF doesn't support `{x:Bind}`.

Second - I don't believe there is or that there needs to be a way. `{x:Bind}` is essentially generating code to update the binding source and view model, so if you don't want to use `{x:Bind}` in XAML - you're basically going to write the code to update your view properties when your view model properties change and vice versa.

If you look at the generated code (e.g. `obj\MainPage.g.cs`) - you'll see all the generated code for the each `{x:Bind}` you have in your XAML. I think there's still something in the platform that is require to make it work with the generated code, but if you write your own code instead - it will likely be cleaner than what the XAML compiler generates and won't require the platform to do things for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply - no, it isn't.

It's compiled and strong-typed binding, so it's converted to code during the compilation, not in runtime.

The main reason for create binding in code-behind could be some dynamic changes or for example generating of some controls in cycle and setting their properties with binding. But it's not possible as x:Bind could not be modified in runtime, so it could be the reason that this is not possible to edit it in code-behind.